# Can a relation be both anti-reflexive and anti-symmetric?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Is it possible for a relation to be both anti-reflexive and anti-symmetric?

Comment: The empty relation works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't $(\mathbb R,<)$ have both of these properties?

Comment: Isn't that asymmetric rather than anti-symmetric?

Comment: I see so in this case it is vacuously true.

Comment: A relation $R$ is antisymmetric if "$xRy$ and $yRx$" implies "$x=y$". This is true for my relation because the hypothesis is never satisfied (so the implication is vacuously true).